# C++ Function may return different vectors based on a passed parameter-but I get compiler warning

Tags: c++, vector, warnings

I have a function like this:

```
vector<double> MyClass::MyFunc(string Parm)
{
if(Parm=="A")
  return Vector1
else if (Parm=="B")
  return Vector2
}
```

I get the compiler warning "function must return a value". Should I just ignore this or is there a way to eliminate it? If the return value was a standard data type instead of a vector, I know the answer. Vector1 and Vector2 are data members of the same class.
TIA,
Fred Emmerich

Comment: fwiw, you should never ignore a warning. Also dont eleminate the warning but the issue that caused the warning

Comment: The compiler can't ensure that only valid values are passed to this function. Imagine you take user input and pass it to this function, and the user inputs "C". What is the code going to do?

Comment: If the design of your function is such that it only ever should receive "A" or "B", then at least have it throw an error as a last resort if you don't want it to return some default value.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know that those are the only values that will ever be passed to the function?

Answer (score 3):

Your function does not return a value when `Param != A && param != B`,

you can solve this by adding `else return VectorX` or `return VectorX` on the last line.

P.S. try optimizing your if-statements and functions, I would rather have your function as follows:

```
vector<double>* MyClass::MyFunc(const string& param)
{
if(!strcmp(param,"A")) return &m_vector1;
else if (!strcmp(param,"B")) return &m_vector2;

return nullptr;
}
```

Where `m_vector1` and `m_vector2` are member variables of your class.

Comment: I have no idea why you're using `strcmp` here. It doesn't make sense to pass a `std::string` to a function expecting `char*` (hint: it won't compile). Just do the obvious, and correct, thing and use `if (param == "A")`

Comment: You're right, im used to wxString which does work. But double quotes for one character are a waste anyway.

Comment: The pointer example looks to be the best fit for me. My code passes only A or B, nothing else. I was just trying to avoid having 2 functions, one for A and one for B. All the function does is retrieve a data member of a class that happens to be a vector. If it was a standard data type, like int, i would just create a default return of 0.